# ARP request with unicast MAC?

Tags: arp, wireshark

Regarding ARP requests, I got to believe that the destination MAC address was in all situations the broadcast address.

Yet I got across this Wireshark capture:

[image: ARP wireshark capture]

I just cannot understand the 3rd request from my router. Why is the destination MAC address of the request set to my NIC and not as broadcast? The last ARP request from the router is exactly how I would assume it to be (i.e., using the broadcast MAC address)

*(.1 is a router, .100 my PC, .103 second PC)*

Comment: What is the router model, software version, etc.?

Comment: The router is unfortunately not "under my control" so I cannot get the info. I thought it was directly a feature of ARP and the model of the router did not matter. Will try to obtain it in the near future.

Comment: Questions about networks not under your control are explicitly off-topic here. The [help/on-topic] details which topics are on-topic, and which topics are off-topic. You can try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: I issued a question about ARP, did not know those information would be required for this kind of question, my apologies. Will try what you suggested.

Comment: Just want to ask additional question if possible. Does that mean it's not a regular behavior of ARP and it probably depends on the model of the router?

Comment: It seems to be a strange gratuitous ARP, which should normally be sent to the broadcast MAC address. It's hard to say because that router may have been configured to do this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In an attempt to refresh an expired, or expiring, ARP entry, many Client OS's will issue a "targeted" ARP query to the MAC address they already expect. Most of the time, this prompts a response from the intended target and allows the entry to be refreshed without sending a broadcast to the entire network.

This will be the first time I've seen it with a Router, but it isn't too big of a stretch to think a Router vendor somewhere will have implemented ARP in the same way.

*Nearly a Year Later Edit*: I found a quote in [RFC 1122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt) that describes this behavior:

> ```
> 2.3.2  Address Resolution Protocol -- ARP
>    2.3.2.1  ARP Cache Validation
>       An implementation of the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP)
>       MUST provide a mechanism to flush out-of-date cache
>       entries.  If this mechanism involves a timeout, it SHOULD be
>
>       ...
>
>       IMPLEMENTATION:
>            Four mechanisms have been used, sometimes in
>            combination, to flush out-of-date cache entries.
>
>            ...
>
>            (2)  Unicast Poll -- Actively poll the remote host by
>                 periodically sending a point-to-point ARP Request
>                 to it, and delete the entry if no ARP Reply is
>                 received from N successive polls.  Again, the
>                 timeout should be on the order of a minute, and
>                 typically N is 2.
> ```