# Router issued ARP requests Target MAC = Broadcast, Host issued ARP requests Target MAC = 0's?

Tags: arp

**Why does an ARP request from my Router have a Target MAC Address: Broadcast** 
[image]

**While Host issued ARP requests always have Target MAC Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00?**
[image]

**Also, I periodically see ARP requests generated by a host going to the router, but it already includes the correct Target MAC address. What is that all about?**
[image]

Comment: You need to edit your question to give some examples.

Comment: And specific devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [RFC 826](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826) doesn't specify what address to use, but indeed explicitly allow any address:

> (ar$tha) Hardware address of target of this
> packet (if known).
> [...]
> It does not set ar$tha to anything in particular, because it is this
> value that it is trying to determine.  It could set ar$tha to the
> broadcast address for the hardware (all ones in the case of the 10Mbit
> Ethernet) if that makes it convenient for some aspect of the
> implementation.

So each implementation is free to use the broadcast address or not.

RFC826 is updated by [RFC 5227](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5227#section-1.2), but it doesn't change this:

> This document does not modify any of the protocol rules in RFC 826.
> It does not modify the packet format, or the meaning of any of the
> fields.  The existing rules for "Packet Generation" and "Packet
> Reception" still apply exactly as specified in RFC 826.

Nor does [RFC5494](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5494), the other RFC that update RFC826

Regarding the request that already include the MAC addresses see [RFC5227 section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5227#section-2.3):

> 2.3.  Announcing an Address
>
> Having probed to determine that a desired address may be used
> safely,    a host implementing this specification MUST then announce
> that it    is commencing to use this address by broadcasting
> ANNOUNCE_NUM ARP    Announcements, spaced ANNOUNCE_INTERVAL seconds
> apart.  An ARP    Announcement is identical to the ARP Probe described
> above, except    that now the sender and target IP addresses are both
> set to the    host's newly selected IPv4 address.  The purpose of
> these ARP    Announcements is to make sure that other hosts on the
> link do not    have stale ARP cache entries left over from some other
> host that may    previously have been using the same address.  The
> host may begin    legitimately using the IP address immediately after
> sending the first    of the two ARP Announcements; the sending of the
> second ARP    Announcement may be completed asynchronously, concurrent
> with other    networking operations the host may wish to perform.

Comment: @Lijok Yep forgot this point of your question, I added the answer to this also.

Comment: ARP entries typically need to be refreshed periodically, which is likely what you're seeing in the 3rd example. In order to reduce resource utilization of all of the hosts in the broadcast domain, a unicast ARP request can be sent directly to the router to confirm if it is still alive. I would expect that if the router didn't respond to the unicast ARP request then the host would probably try again with a broadcast ARP request to see if gets an answer. I have seen this behavior many times myself, but my reasoning is technically speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Your third question was answered in this thread:
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/28807

A client may refresh its ARP entries by using *unicast* polling of the already known peer.
I know my home router does this a lot. Every 30 seconds or so, it sends a unicast ARP request to my computer.

User halfmetaljacket above was correct in his assumptions.

According to [RFC1222](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt) :

> Unicast Poll -- Actively poll the remote host by
>                   periodically sending a point-to-point ARP Request
>                   to it, and delete the entry if no ARP Reply is
>                   received from N successive polls.  Again, the
>                   timeout should be on the order of a minute, and
>                   typically N is 2.

That's a great find by user [Eddie](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/users/3675/eddie)